# Logistic regression and IV that depends on another IV value

Tags: logistic, multivariate-analysis, modeling, predictor

I am modeling the effect of aspects of house change and marital status change on a (binomial) DV. Each observation in my data is a 3-year period in someone's life. Thus, for family change, I have a variable called marital_change, with 3 levels: "no marriage", "married" and "already married". For house change, I'd like to investigate if a change occurring has an effect on the DV, plus 3 aspects of the change: whether it was to a a house further/closer/similar distance from city center, whether it was to a more/less/equally mixed-use neighbourhood and whether it was to a more/less/equally urbanized area.

**Question:** What would be a sound way to model the variables describing the aspects of the change, given that they have a dependence on a change existing? (There can only be a change in distance from city center when there is a house change). The introduction about family change was meant to make it clear that I'd prefer not to split data in two sets, one in which all periods include a change. I can also think of having a categorical variable that describes both whether the change happened and the characteristics of the change, but given the number of combinations in the 3 aspects of the house change, that doesn't sound sensible...